# Display content of all .txt files in a directory using CMD

Tags: command-line, cmd, command-prompt

I wish to navigate to a directory and display in the cmd window all of the content of each `.txt` file within.

I have done this much:

1. Navigated to the folder
2. Open a single text file by passing the name `type abc.txt`

*There may be 10 or even 20 `.txt` files in the directory*.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Rewritten for reading and comprehension improvement.

Comment: you can use a `for` loop to do more fancy stuff. type `help for` at command prompt to get details. ... here is an example `FOR %a IN ( *.txt) DO  @echo ------ & @echo filename : %a & @echo ------ & type %a & @echo ------`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using the wildcard character *:
`type *.txt`